# Как сохранить данные о последовательности элементов?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Имеется RecyclerView c возможностью перемещать элементы.
Данные айтемов хранятся в БД.
Как сохранить данные о последовательности элементов, чтобы отсортировать список после получения из БД, чтобы передать его в RecyclerView ?

Comment: Что у вас вызывает сложности? Сохранение в БД? Определение последовательности? Или что?

Comment: В БД храняться серриализованные объекты. Из БД я достаю их и получаю List в определенной последовательности (по порядку id в БД). Но в RecyclerView должна быть своя последовательность, ту которую определил пользователь перетаскивая элементы. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Добавить еще одно поле в базу, не думали ?

Answer (score 0):

В БД делаете отдельное поле, которое будет хранить порядок сортировки. При перемещении элементов сохраняете в это поле текущюю позицию. При выборке сортируете курсор по этому полю.